# How to fill a LongListSelector with the results of a search in the Contacts.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contacts, longlistselector

I am just a beginner at programming and I am trying to make a windows phone application in my application i want to be able to select contacts. I first put it in a list box and it works perfect but I want to make it better so I want to put it into a Longlistselector. This is where the problems occur. 
This is the error I get:    'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'SearchCompleted' and no extension method 'SearchCompleted' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

I no its not the assembly but that's where i get lost. I have the long listlongselector perfect in the xaml but this is where i keep getting lost.

```
namespace contacts
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    int TapCount = 0;

    List<Contacts> contacts = new List<Contacts>();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);
        SearchContacts(String.Empty); 

    }

    private async void SayWords(string words)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        await synth.SpeakTextAsync(words);


    }




    void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        ContactList.ItemsSource = contacts;
    }

    private void SearchContacts(string searchterm)
    {
        contacts.SearchAsync(searchterm, FilterKind.DisplayName, null);
    }  


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a `List` of `Contacts`. A`List` doesn't have a `SearchCompleted` event. The `Contacts` class does. Next, the `ItemSource` of your `LongListSelecter` should be set to `e.Results` in the event handler:

```
namespace contacts
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        int TapCount = 0;

        var contacts = new Contacts();

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);
            SearchContacts(String.Empty); 
        }

        void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            ContactList.ItemsSource = e.Results;
        }

        private void SearchContacts(string searchterm)
        {
            contacts.SearchAsync(searchterm, FilterKind.DisplayName, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.